# Java reflection not agreeing with method declaration

Tags: java, reflection, struts

Sorry about the length of this question.  I'm new to Java and I've come across something that is really stumping me.  I'm so new to Java that I don't even know all the terminology yet, so please bear with me; I have about 3 years of PHP experience (mostly procedural, not OO), but very little Java.  I'm also aware that debugging with System.out.println is the Wrong Way to do it, but it works and it's what I'm used to (insert joke about PHP programmers here if you must).  I'm still trying to figure out how to use the NetBeans debugger.

I'm working on adding a feature to a web application that uses Struts (1.x).  The problem I'm having seems to be that a method is declared to want a String passed to it, but doing Reflection on that method says it wants String[] (a string array).  I'm constrained in that I can't really make major structural changes to the app, and of course I have to make sure that I don't break anything in the app that is currently working, so I'm trying to make my changes in the context of what's already there.  So, to the problem...

Here is where the method is declared (many many lines cut from these to show only what I hope are the relevant bits):

AEReportBean.java:

```
public class AEReportBean {
    private String selectedDownloadFields = null;

    public String getSelectedDownloadFields() {
        return selectedDownloadFields;
    }

    // Note that there is no overloading of this function anywhere, this is the only declaration.
    public void setSelectedDownloadFields(String selectedDownloadFields) {
        this.selectedDownloadFields = selectedDownloadFields;
    }
}
```

When the user clicks Submit on the form, it gets handled by AEReportSubmitAction.java:

```
public class AEReportSubmitAction extends BaseAction {
    public ActionForward doExecute(
            ActionMapping mapping,
            ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response
        ) throws Exception {
        // This works fine, the paramater is getting passed in the request:
        System.out.println("URL parameter: " + request.getParameter("selectedDownloadFields");

        AEReportBean bean = new AEReportBean(request.getLocale(), 0);

        PropertyUtil.setAllFromRequest(request, bean);
        // This prints "Null", meaning the setAllFromRequest line above is failing to set this property.
        System.out.println("AEReportSubmitAction.java - bean.getSelectedDownloadFields() after setAllFromRequest: " + bean.getSelectedDownloadFields());
    }
}
```

PropertyUtil.setAllFromRequest() is where the magic, and the real problem, happens:

```
public class PropertyUtil {
    /**
     * Takes all the parameters from the request object and if there's a matching
     * mutator method in the bean, sets it
     */
    static public void setAllFromRequest(ServletRequest request, Object out) {
        // Iterate through all the request parameter names and try to set each one.
        for (Enumeration parameterNames = request.getParameterNames(); parameterNames.hasMoreElements();) {
            String name = (String) parameterNames.nextElement();
            try {
                PropertyUtil.setSimpleProperty(out, name, request.getParameter(name));
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                log.info("Exception while setting properties from the Request. parameterName=" + name, e);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets the property from an object using the object's mutator method.
     * Assumes naming conventions for accessor methods
     * @param bean the object to get the property from
     * @param property the name of the property to obtain
     * @param newProperty the object to set
     */
    // NOTE: This just seems to be a wrapper for the method below it...
    static public void setSimpleProperty(Object bean, String property, Object newProperty) throws Exception {
        PropertyUtil.setSimpleProperty(bean, property, newProperty, null);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the property from an object using the object's mutator method.
     * Assumes naming conventions for accessor methods
     * @param bean the object to get the property from
     * @param property the name of the property to obtain
     * @param newProperty the object to set
     */
    static public void setSimpleProperty(Object bean, String property, Object newProperty, Class type) throws Exception {
        // Capitalize the first letter in the property and append "set" to the front
        String methodName = "set" + property.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + property.substring(1);
        Method method;

        Class[] parameters;

        // If the Type was passed in when this method was called, simply add it to the Class array.
        if (type != null) {
            parameters = new Class[]{type};
        }
        // If the Type was not specified, determine the Type's class by calling getClass() on it; that class will be used below to call the appropriate setter method.
        else {
            parameters = new Class[]{newProperty.getClass()};
        }

        // Here's the reflection problem...
        // Iterate through all the methods in the bean.  If the method is named "setSelectedDownloadFields", print out some info about it.
        for (Method m : bean.getClass().getMethods()) {
            if (m.getName().equals("setSelectedDownloadFields")) {
                // newProperty is the incoming data that ultimately comes from the HTML form field.
                System.out.println("newProperty.getClass(): " + newProperty.getClass()); // Prints "class java.lang.String"

                    // Added for Cameron Skinner in comments.
                    System.out.println("m.toGenericString: " + m.toGenericString()); // Prints "public void com.[company deleted].bean.AEReportBean.setSelectedDownloadFields(java.lang.String[])"

                System.out.println("m.getName(): " + m.getName()); // Prints "setSelectedDownloadFields"
                System.out.println("parameters:");
                for (Class c : m.getParameterTypes()) {
                    System.out.println("--c.getCanonicalName(): " + c.getCanonicalName()); // Prints "java.lang.String[]"
                    System.out.println("--c.getName(): " + c.getName()); // Prints "[Ljava.lang.String;"
                }
            }
        }


        // And here's where it fails...
        try {
            System.out.println("bean.getClass(): " + bean.getClass());  // Prints "class com.[company deleted].bean.AEReportBean"
            System.out.println("methodName: " + methodName); // Prints "setSelectedDownloadFields"
            System.out.println("for (Class p : parameters):");
            for (Class p : parameters) {
                System.out.println("--p.getCanonicalName(): " + p.getCanonicalName()); // Prints "java.lang.String"
            }

            // Here it looks for a method called, effectively, AEReportBean.setSelectedDownloadFields(String s), but above we see that reflection is showing it as AEReportBean.setSelectedDownloadFields(String[] s), so the try block fails.
            method = bean.getClass().getMethod(methodName, parameters);
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // All lines below here also fail until it bombs out with the exception at the bottom...

            // If no method can be found, then see if it's a primitive type that
            // has been wrapped
            Class valueClass = newProperty.getClass();
            //System.out.println("valueClass.toString() = " + valueClass.toString());
            try {
                if (valueClass.equals(Integer.class)) {
                    method = bean.getClass().getMethod(methodName, new Class[]{int.class});
                }
                else if (valueClass.equals(Double.class)) {
                    method = bean.getClass().getMethod(methodName, new Class[]{double.class});
                }
                else if (valueClass.equals(Long.class)) {
                    method = bean.getClass().getMethod(methodName, new Class[]{long.class});
                }
                else if (valueClass.equals(Float.class)) {
                    method = bean.getClass().getMethod(methodName, new Class[]{float.class});
                }
                else {
                    throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
                throw new Exception(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }

        // If it had gotten to this point, it would call the method with the appropriate parameters, and the property would be set.
        try {
            // Now execute the method
            method.invoke(bean, new Object[]{newProperty});
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new Exception(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

I really don't know what I'm missing here, but there must be something.  Other HTML form elements on the same page work perfectly.  Please let me know if any more information is needed.  Thanks!

Comment: What does the struts-config.xml look like?

Comment: Can you add a call to `m.toGenericString()` inside your `for (Method m : bean.getClass().getMethods()) {if (m.getName().equals("setSelectedDownloadFields")) {` loop? I'd be interested to see what it says.

Comment: @stjohnroe: Relevant lines of struts-config.xml:

    <action path="/aeReportSubmit" type="com.[company deleted].actions.AEReportSubmitAction">
     <forward name="backToList" path="/aeReportList.do" />
     <!--<forward name="error" path=".error" />-->
     <forward name="incorrectFields" path="/aeReportDetail.do" />
     <forward name="success" path=".aeReportConfirm" />
    </action> (Sorry, code formatting doesn't seem to work in comments...)

Comment: @Cameron Skinner: m.toGenericString() inside that loop prints "public void com.[company deleted].bean.AEReportBean.setSelectedDownloadFields(java.lang.String[])"

Comment: @Sam: Hmm. Weird. I'm stumped :(

Comment: Note the Java varargs syntax. Writing `setSelectedDownloadFields(String... selectedDownloadFields)` will make the method expect an array of Strings. Any chance the parameter is defined with `String...` and not `String`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code results doesn't lie. It's basically telling that the class isn't what you expect it to be. You've multiple `AEReportBean` classes of different versions in the classpath of your project, possibly in different packages, and the wrong one has been imported or got precedence in classloading. Do a Type/Class search in Netbeans to find all classes by the given name in the classpath *(I don't do Netbeans, but in Eclispe it's Ctrl+Shift+T, the Netbeans equivalent is probably Alt+Shift+O)*.

**Update**: another possible cause is that Netbeans didn't build the project automatically on save of the source file (an IDE should create/refresh `.class` files during build). Look somewhere in settings.

Comment: I'll double check this when I get to work tomorrow, but the selectedDownloadFields method was added by me and I only put it in the one file.  I've done full text searches against the entire SVN checkout to make sure, because overloading was also the first thing I thought of, but I'll check again.  I know computers always do what you say and not what you mean, so somewhere I must be telling it the wrong thing, but hell if I can figure out where...  I'll update tomorrow on the results.

Comment: +1 for BalusC, try to change AEReportBean in some way to be sure it's the one your application is seeing...

Comment: OK, I added a couple System.out.println() calls to AEReportBean.java (one in the constructor and two in other setters that should be called along with the setSelectedDownloadFields() and that are working correctly).  None of the prints showed up in the output...  But, I did a full text search for "aereportbean" and it only shows up in 5 files including AEReportBean.java.  None of the other files it's in have anything but their own classes; as far as I can tell, AEReportBean is not declared anywhere else.  Same results searching in NetBeans.  Any ideas why my printlns aren't showing up though?

Comment: Because it's not the class you expect it to be. I'd suggest to do a local disk file system search on filename `AEReportBean.class` and `AEReportBean.java`. If that gives nothing, then it's likely in one of the JAR files. Or maybe the class file has simply not been updated by Netbeans.  I don't do Netbeans, but in Eclipse there's an option to automatically build the project whenever you save a source file. Maybe it's been turned off in Netbeans so that no new class file has been generated.

Comment: @BalusC: I think you're on to something here... AEReportBean.class has a date of 12/08, but all the other class files have a date of this morning!  I moved the AEReportBean.class file out of that folder, hoping that would force a refresh, but it gave compiler errors and bombed out, so I'm looking for a way to do it through NetBeans.  I think this may be it though.  I'll keep you posted...

Comment: @BalusC: IT WORKED!!  AEReportBean.java had somehow gotten moved to another folder.  No idea how, and NetBeans never complained about anything so it didn't even occur to me.  But I moved it back to where it belongs, recompiled, the .class file updated, and now it's working!  Thanks!